# Do we have send email feature in Open Stack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

We have a requirement of password reset in OpenStack-Keystone. Keystone API provides API for password resetting but I would like to know if there is a service that can help us trigger email once an account is created in KeyStone. We would like to send an email once an account is created with default password so that user can set his/her first-time password and then only account gets activated.

Comment: To the people who downvote question: Please leave a comment telling "Why". That will help author and everyone understand your intention better.

Answer (score 0):

The `zaqar` is the messaging service component in openstack. You need to integrate and configure this component to make use of it.

**https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/config-reference/messaging.html

Comment: thank you for your reply. So what you are saying is that we can trigger emails using this service if configured properly? I have not looked at the link yet, I am going to explore it now. Do you know anything that is within keystone itself by any chance?